# Is a large class path of multiple (perhaps even unused) jar files inefficient

Tags: java, performance, memory, jar

The way I see it, (correct me if I'm wrong) a class is cached, so that the need to search the class path is only necessary the first time the class is referenced. It will only happen as often as the static initializer is called, which is only one time during the life cycle of the program. (or more specifically, the Class Loader)

But in the case of a large, long-life program that includes many many libraries that may or may not be used.

Do the Jar files get loaded into memory, causing unnecessary usage due to the fact that most of the classes are never used? Will it stay in Memory?

Is referencing a directory a better option? Or is the Jar file already unzipped into a temporary location to begin with?

Is it faster to use the directory method than the Jar file method?

Is it reasonable to extract all Jar files into a single directory, to reduce the number of locations in the class path? When is this a good idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jar file central directories (placed at the end of zips) will be parsed and loaded into memory. The directory is flat so all of it needs to be loaded. A significant part of the delay when starting a simple Java process is the opening of rt.jar which is huge. So, yes that's start up time and memory overhead right there.

Look up for each class should be constant time. However, there are some O(n) algorithms there. So for an application as a whole that O(n^2) for class loading (although the constant is quite small and may well be dominated by linear time operations).

Doing file access on loads of files will be inefficient. The JDK was using a zip for system classes before jars.

(Class loading may happen some time before static initialisation when the static initialiser will be run if present - see three-argument `Class.forName`.)

Comment: The central directory is not eagerly parsed just mapped (mmap) into memory and resolved when necessary (I do not recall the code perfectly well but feel almost positive)

Comment: **Doing file access on loads of files will be inefficient. The JDK was using a zip for system classes before jars.** This is an interesting point. The way I see it, using a jar (or zip) file is a trade-off. Using the extra memory means that class loading is faster. Thank you for your information.

Comment: @bestsss When trying to find a class, each jar will need to be opened in term. You'd be very lucky to happen to have all your classes in the early jars. You might also have problems looking for resources for example.

Comment: Yes, jars are checked one by one and if a class doesn't exist it takes whole lookup (bootstrap+system+local classloader, etc). Indeed, CEN is hash-indexed by entry name (name->address), so each entry takes only 5.33 (4/.75f) bytes of memory, the rest is kept as memory mapped file (virtual memory). rt.jar has around 17k files, that's probably 500k to read.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline did anything change in recent releases of Java?

Answer (score 11):

This is so not a problem, you shouldn't worry about it. The class loader is smart enough to load the classes it needs, and often loads classes on demand (i.e. it's not typically going to load up a bunch of code that isn't going to be used). This has nothing to do with how large or long running your application is.

In the case of a large number of JARs I'd be more concerned about [JAR Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell).

As far as the question of faster, I suppose there might be some difference between the various approaches, but if there is you can easily test this yourself by just trying it via experimentation. The situation is likely application specific, since the code that each application loads is different.

I think [smooth reggae's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881190/smooth-reggae) answer is good for some additional detail on the class loading topic.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Also from my understanding certain JVM's implement the -client and -server JVM parms. The -client parm tells the JVM to only load classes as needed (and even garbage collect classes not used for a while) to speed up initial firing up of your application. The -server option causes the JVM to load slower as it analyzes the classes loaded and looks to see which ones it should keep in memory longer based on usage. If you have a long running application, the -server option is often worth it. Again, check your JVM to see if has these parms.

Comment: @normalocity, We will be careful. **"two different versions of a library"** will be avoided like the plague. **"require different versions"** will probably never occur, but if it does, we will take care of it with either a separate process or classloader. **"several (potentially very many) nested, cooperating classloaders"** will be prevented by design.  However, the question is only partially answered. Are all the jar files loaded into memory? By this, I mean class files, not actual classes.

Comment: @Chris, the only difference between C1 (client) and C2 (compiler) is in the profiling and time take to analyze + more aggressive inline+ optimization of C2. Class loading is exactly the same w/ C1/C2 and interpreter.  Classes are kept in memory regardless c1/c2 and jar loading is abstracted from the memory representation.

Answer (score 4):

[How classes are found](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) and [the chapter on loading, linking and initializing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html) in the JVM specification are useful references.

From personal experience, I can attest that the longer your classpath for `javac` the more time your compilation will take; this is especially a problem when your classpath features JARs that are not required for compilation. For a simple test, try compiling the canonical HelloWorld.java without `-cp`, with a couple of JAR files added to `-cp` and then with several JAR files added to `-cp`; the time taken for compilation goes up as the number of JARs in the `-cp` list goes up.

Comment: Interesting point about compiling. For my specific case however, the long classpath is only for runtime. Not compile time, as that happens in small parts.